# pandas create median over rows on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

So, say I have a sample DataFrame as:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A", "B", "C"], "total_1": [1, 2, 3], "total_2": [7, 8, 9], "total_3": [9, 10, 11]}
```

What I would like to do is create a new dataframe which contains the median over all columns which contain the substring `total` and to do it along the row. i.e. the new data frame would have a column which should be `[7, 8, 9]`.

I tthink I would be able to do it if I could sub-select the columns with `total` in their names and then compute median along axis 1 but I am not sure how to do this selection. I do not know apriori how many such columns I will have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x['median']=x.filter(like='total').apply(lambda x: x.median(), axis=1)



 Name  total_1  total_2  total_3  median
0    A        1        7        9     7.0
1    B        2        8       10     8.0
2    C        3        9       11     9.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Select your columns using a list comprehension, then apply the median as you stated:

```py
cols = [col for col in x.columns if 'total' in col]

x['newcol'] = x[cols].median(axis=1)

  Name  total_1  total_2  total_3  newcol
0    A        1        7        9     7.0
1    B        2        8       10     8.0
2    C        3        9       11     9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning was spot on. Here it is in code.

```py
# Declare list that contains all columns that contain the string 'total'
cols = [col for col in x.columns if 'total' in col]

# Declare median as new column
x['median'] = x[cols].median(axis=1)

# Result
print(x)
  Name  total_1  total_2  total_3  median
0    A        1        7        9     7.0
1    B        2        8       10     8.0
2    C        3        9       11     9.0
```

Note that `axis=1` tells `median()` to operate along the columns, row by row. So it does the operations horizontally.